# AWS Route 53 SES configuration

Tags: email, amazon-web-services

I am using route 53 for my domain and gmail for my email client. I am routing all emails to my domain to gmails nameservers. I want to intercept a few different email addresses so they can be recieved by SES. How would I go about defining a record set to do this? Or is there another way to do this? I would like to avoid redirecting emails from mail@mydomain.com or mail-(some-random-token)@mydomain.com